# Git browse through non-empty commits

Tags: git, gitx, tig, gitg

I work on this project which has *many* commits with empty changesets. As much as I would like to run `git filter-branch` and remove those commits, this is really not an option.

Are there any tools (e.g. gitg tig) that would allow me to *browse through only the non-empty commits*? By browsing I mean viewing the (non-empty) commit list and easily view the diff of a commit of interest.

Comment: I don't have a repository with empty commits at hand to test this on. Does `git log --ignore-blank-lines` do what you want?

Comment: @Barend not really, what I really would like to have is a revision/commit browser from which I can enter/exit the diff of a specific commit. I use `tig` to do that all the time, but I haven't found a way to make it ignore empty commits.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party but you can add a file filter argument:

```
tig -- .
```

This means that tig will only show commits that touch any file under the "." directory (which is just any file when running from the repo root).